# How can I detect if a column in a csv contains a certain value using Python?

Tags: python

when i input a currency (using ISO 4217 code) as an argument it should display whether or not the currency is supported in the application

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Cheap.Stocks.Internationalization.Currencies.Csv')

data = data[['Country', 'Currency', 'ISO 4217 Code']]

all_data = data.values


user = ''

for i in all_data:

    user = input('Enter currency: ')
    if user in i:
        print(i.split())
```

Comment: Forgive me for the code,  i'm new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the data looks like

```
data = [["DEU", "Euro", "EUR" ],
["USA", "Dollar", "USD"],
["FRA", "Euro", "EUR"]]
```

Thus to detect whether `user` is in the 3rd column of data, you can do this in one command (plus include):

```
import numpy as np
if user in np.array(data)[:,2]:
    doFancyStuff
```

Comment: @ButtonupD please don't shout at me 

Comment: Lol. Much respect.